# $ \ (\mathbb{Z}/(n),+)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

May I know if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Definition:

$\mathbb{Z}/(n)= \{[a]_n: a \in \{0,...,n-1\}\}, \text{where} \ [a]_n=\{b \in \mathbb{Z}: n |(b-a)\}$

$(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)=\{s+n\mathbb{Z}: s\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

$n\mathbb{Z}=\{0,\pm n,\pm 2n, \pm3n,...\}$

$\text{Claim:}  \ (\mathbb{Z}/(n),+)=(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},+)$

$\text{Pf}: x \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

$\implies \exists q \in \mathbb{Z}\exists r \in \{0,...,n-1\}:x=nq+r+n\mathbb{Z}=r+n\mathbb{Z}$

$\implies \forall y \in x\exists m \in \mathbb{Z}: y=r + nm$

$\implies x \subseteq [r]_n$

$\forall y' \in [r]_n \exists m' \in \mathbb{Z}: y'=nm'+r $

$\implies [r]_n \subseteq x.$

$\text{i.e.}\  \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \subseteq   \mathbb{Z}/(n)$

$\ y \in \mathbb{Z}/(n)$

$\implies \exists r \in\{0,...,n-1\}:y=[r]_n$

$\forall z \in y\ \exists m \in \mathbb{Z}:nm=z-r$

$\implies \ z\in r+n\mathbb{Z} $

$\forall z' \in r+n\mathbb{Z} \ \exists m' \in \mathbb{Z}:z'=r+nm'$

$\implies z' \in [r]_n.$

$\text{i.e.}\  \mathbb{Z}/(n) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: What is the difference between $(n)$ and $n\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $(n)$, $\mathbb Z/(n)$ and $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$

Comment: @andraiamatrix, $x$ is a coset in Alexy's notation. I think it's fine. Anyway, as has been mentioned, aren't $(n)$ and $n\Bbb{Z}$ the same thing?

Comment: $\text{Let}\ n\in \mathbb{N}.\ \mathbb{Z}/(n)= \{[a]_n: a \in \{0,...,n-1\}\}, \text{where} \ [a]_n=\{b \in \mathbb{Z}: n |(b-a)\}$

Comment: @Alexy: I think you are using $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ to mean $\{0,1,2,3,\dots, n-1\}$ and $+$ to mean addition modulo $n$. In my travels I've always seen this written as $\Bbb Z_n$, whereas $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/(n)$ are identical objects (even as sets!).

Comment: @EricStucky, please see my edits.

Comment: So what you are really trying to prove is that $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ is a set of coset representatives of $n{\mathbb Z}$ in ${\mathbb Z}$?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo: Please have a look if my post is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the following group isomorphism: 
\begin{align*}
\phi: \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z&\to\mathbb Z_n,\\~~m+n\mathbb Z&\mapsto m,\quad 0\leq m<n
\end{align*}
then your way is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the first direction is correct but poorly written. At the underlying level, mathematics is axiomatized by nothing but formulae and rules for their manipulation, but at the level of human mathematicians such writing style is usually considered very bad. (Yes, Russell's *Principia Mathematica* is an obvious exception, but you are not working in set theory, you are working in abstract algebra.)

Your proof of the second direction is nonexistent (as I'm sure you're aware). I agree that the proof is obvious, but it is not dramatically more obvious than the first proof, which you proved in great detail. So it is confusing to me that you would not carry the second one out as well. If you intended to say that the *argument* carries over to the second proof, I cannot really argue with this. But your proof was not sufficiently explained to allow a reader to understand your argument at a "high level", so I would not consider this to be a gap of acceptable size.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have now proved the converse as well. How should I present my argument? I thought I would sound confusing if I replace those symbols with words

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo: If you use the right words, it won't be confusing :P In seriousness, though: try writing up a first draft, maybe post it as another question, and I'll do my best to revise it.

Comment: Shall we converse on facebook? :)

Comment: @Alexy: There is a chat feature on this site, if you just want to talk it out. We can create a room for just us, too. Honestly, though, I think it would be better for you to think through the first draft alone. But if you want to chat about the revisions, can we delay our meeting until this time tomorrow? I am occupied for a good part of the rest of today, but I don't know how much. EDIT: [I have flagged you in chat and given instructions](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12895487#12895487) :P

Comment: @Alexy: The situation has changed and I am available for the rest of the day :)